# TypeError: a float is required

Tags: python, math, pytorch

l have a pytorch variable :

```
preds[4,4]
Out[305]: 
Variable containing:
-96.7809
[torch.cuda.FloatTensor of size 1 (GPU 0)]
```

l want to do the following :

```
 import math
 x=preds[4,4]
 y=maths.exp(x)
 z= y / (y+1)
```

However when l do :

```
y=maths.exp(x)
```

l get the following error :

```
   math.exp(preds[4,4])
TypeError: a float is required
```

How can l transform a torch variable to a float in order to be able to do these operations ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing a `Variable` object doesnt convert it into a scalar. Its still a `Variable` object. However indexing a `numpy array` does. So converting the `Variable` object into a numpy and then indexing the way you want it should do the trick.

But there are some small pitfalls when converting a `Variable` to numpy.

If `preds` is a `Variable` stored in cpu memory, you can simply do this.

```
nparr = preds.data.numpy()
x = nparr[4, 4]
```

However, if `preds` is in gpu memory, you will have to first transfer the `Variable` into cpu memory before you convert it into a numpy object, like so:

```
preds = preds.cpu()
```

and then do the same as above.

```
nparr = preds.data.numpy()
x = nparr[4, 4]
```

In both cases `x` is a scalar (a float in your case) and you can use it in any math operations you choose.

## Edit:

yes, @mexmex is right, you could also directly index the `tensor` that is wrapped in the `Variable` to extract the scalar value at any given index.

Like so:

```
 x = preds.data[4, 4]
```

Comment: Can you not actually dispense with the numpy conversion if you index the data tensor directly? preds.data[4,4] returns a scalar.